# Message passing from destructor during garbage collection

Tags: d

The following gives me an Access Violation on windows 32-bit, dmd.2.052, no flags.  When the destructor is run by the garbage collector, the message box seems to be corrupted in the process.

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;
import core.memory;
import std.concurrency;

class C
{
    string m_str;
    Tid m_receiverTid;
    this(string s, Tid rt) { this.m_str = s; this.m_receiverTid = rt; }
    ~this() {   writeln("Destructor : ",this.m_str);
                m_receiverTid.send(this.m_str);
            }
}


void receiver() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                receive((string s){writeln("Received: ",s);});
            }
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            writeln("Caught throwable: ",th.toString());
        }
}

void main() {
    Tid receiverTid = spawn(&receiver);

    receiverTid.send("Basic test");
    Thread.sleep( 5_000_000 );

    C c1 = new C("c1 Manually deleted",receiverTid);
    delete c1;
    Thread.sleep( 5_000_000 );

    {
        C c2 = new C("c2 Garbage collected",receiverTid);
    }
    writeln("Running garbage collector..."); // This line needed to flush out the c2 root pointer.
    GC.collect();
    Thread.sleep( 5_000_000 );

    writeln("Exiting main thread...");
}
```

The above produces:

> Received: Basic test
>   Destructor : c1 Manually deleted
>   Received: c1 Manually deleted
>   Running garbage collector...
>   Destructor : c2 Garbage collected
>   Received: c2 Garbage collected
>   Caught throwable: object.Error: Access Violation
>   Exiting main thread...

Are there any workarounds for this?
Is there a way for destructor code to know if it is being invoked by the GC or not?
Is message passing from a destructor intrinsically unsafe, e.g. if non-GC threads are frozen by the GC whilst they have a mutex lock on a shared message box then the GC might deadlock if it sends to a locked message box?  Or does destructor code only take place in a sweep cycle after all threads are thawed?
Is it safe for a destructor to reference thread local storage, e.g. could the GC sweep cycle be in a different thread?

Answer (score 5):

I see two issues here that may be related.  First, [referencing subobjects from a destructor called by the GC is not allowed.](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#destructors)

> Furthermore, the order in which the
>   garbage collector calls destructors
>   for unreference objects is not
>   specified. This means that when the
>   garbage collector calls a destructor
>   for an object of a class that has
>   members that are references to garbage
>   collected objects, those references
>   may no longer be valid. This means
>   that destructors cannot reference sub
>   objects.

Second, as you mention, destructor calls do only take place in the sweep cycle after all threads are resumed.  They may be called from a different thread than the one that owned the object when it was alive.  There are proposals on the table to fix this, but so far none have been implemented.